# Access Denied for user

Tags: php, mysql

I've made a php script to access my database...as far as I can see all login details are right but I get this error message: Access denied for user 'a5247024_thesps'@'10.1.1.36' to database 'maininf'

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("mysql11.000webhost.com", "a5247024_thesps", "******") or     die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("maininf") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "maininf" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maininf")
or die(mysql_error());  

// store the record of the "maininf" table into $row
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of the entry 

echo "Name: ".$row['PUA_Name'];


?>
```

Can anybody please help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You apparently may be confusing table names with database names.  Unless *both* your table and your database are called `maininf`, your call to `mysql_select_db()` probably needs a different string as the actual name of the database, rather than the table name.

```
// Your database name may not be the same as your table name!
// Substitute the correct value in place of maininf here
mysql_select_db("maininf") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "maininf" table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maininf")
or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Awesome Awesome....got a couple of things juggled about wrong....apparently the database was a5247024_maininf, the table was called maininfo_db.....what a wally. Works fine now though. Well done Michael, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to access MySQL from bash using those credentials first.

Then, try adding the port number:

Example:

mysql11.000webhost.com:3306

Also check to see if the user has access permissions to the database "maininf." You can use MySQL's [SHOW GRANTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-grants.html) to see if the DB is available to be read.